# sparkpost email config

Tags: civimail, sparkpost

Trying to set up Sparkpost for Civicrm 5.12.0 / WP 5.1.1 / php 7.2

I was trying the cividesk extension but I'm on the EU server and can't figure out the fiddling needed to access that just yet.

So I've tried setting up smtp. I've configured Admin > Settings > Outbound mail and got a confirmation note from Sparkpost that it works. However, that test email hasn't been subsequently sent - Sparkpost has it as 'accepted' but not gone anywhere.

As advised by Sparkmail - I've set up mail.digilocal.org.uk as my mail subdomain. The sending DNS checks have been verified (DKIM / bounces).

I've tried sending a bulk email (just to myself but using a test group) with the following bounce report:

> authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Ema

I have a FROM email address mail@mail.digilocal.org.uk and have set up a mailbox on my domain with that address. I've also set it up as the default bounce address (which is I guess how I'm getting the report).

I've got two other installations of civicrm working and not had these issues. Not quite sure what's so different with this domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

closing as I think the problem is in CiviCRM - sending test mailing works, whenever I send a full scheduled run it falls over and bounces everything. So the error is in CiviCRM (or my config of it) rather than SparkPost.

Comment: If you get problems when running the scheduled job via cron, but it works when using 'execute now', see if https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/28933/225 applies